# getting confused about .aspx and .html

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, asp.net

i am new to asp.net and i have started learning asp.net and i am excited about it.

my questions are...

1.what is the main difference between .html and .aspx page?

2.i wanted to know is there any difficulty while it comes to apply styles and javascript code to aspx page . till now i have experienced in developing client side applications using html,css,javascript,jquery(static web pages no dynamic data will be loaded). this time i am going to do with .aspx is there any obstacles in making web site beautifully with asp.net ?

Comment: The output of an aspx page is an html page. It's just a way of assembling the content and markup dynamically, on the server side,as opposed to typing it all out beforehand as static html.

Comment: If you are learning ASP.NET, I would steer clear of ASPX and learn MVC/Razor Pages (.cshtml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML** is a Markup language (it defines the page structure)

**CSS** stands for **C**ascading **S**tyles **S**heets they defines the style of the elements in the page

**ASP** is a server side programming language (that means that is elaborated by the web server)

**Javascript** is a clientside programming language (that means that is elaborated by the user's browser)

Basically this is how it works:

Web server process the asp data and then return to the user the HTML result, now the browser can elaborate the html (apply styles from the referred CSS stylesheet, execute Javascript etc.), there is no particular difficulty that other languages doesn't have.

If you want to Know more about Server side languages: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting

**Happy coding!**

Answer (score 5):

**HTML Pag**e : A Web page with user interface and content static information that does not go through any server-side processing.

**ASPX Page** : A Web page with user interface and dynamic content information that is coming from server-side. This type of page will render the HTML content in the browser. ASPX page is dynamic and has server control support.

---

*Is there any difficulty while it comes to apply styles and javascript code to aspx?*

-- The CSS and JS are applied in the aspx pages in the same way as you do it for HTML. The only difference comes when you use Master Page. In that case, you just need to be sure about the `id's` of the elements as they are dynamically generated

Comment: "static information that does not go through any server-side processing" not to be nit-picky but technically wrong since AJAX.

Comment: @Delta heh HTML stands for static pages. The thing you refeered to is known as 
Dynamic HTML, or DHTML, is an umbrella term for a collection of technologies used together to create interactive web sites by using a combination of a static markup language (such as HTML), a client-side scripting language (such as JavaScript)

Comment: @Delta html file retrieved using ajax does not go through any different server side handling than it does opening directly in browser

Comment: @Tushar. Fair enough. Though file types are being discussed, not paradigms. html files could be dynamic or not: you don't change your file extension do dhtml in case you're using ajax on it.

Comment: @Delta well actually this is the time of Web 3.0, but you can actually use a `.dhtml` extension. People dont need to use it because browsers are smarter now ;)

Comment: @Tushar. So, .html extension could be dynamic or not?

Answer (score -1):

There is no problem using Asp.net, you will have the same result because the browser will display the result with HTML and CSS. You can use JavaScript in the same way and you will no have problem in the result.

Asp.net give more advantages to add functionality to your projects.

So, do not be afraid to learn this language :)